# How to remove child element from div using jquery or normal JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, ecmascript-2016

I have a list of user cards. That card contains add and remove button.
I want to remove that card from list of card when I click at remove button.

Code is similar to following:

```
// function to generate card
function generateUserCard(id) {
  return `
    <div class="user-card" id="${id}">
      <button data-id="${id}" class="add" >Add</button>
      <button data-id="${id}" class="remove" >Remove</button>
    </div>
  `;
}

// function to generate list of user 
function generateUsers(users) {
  const userGrid = $("#user-grid");
  for(let user of users) {
    const userCard = generateUserCard(user.id);
    userGrid.append(userCard);
    // adding event listeners
    $(`[data-id=${user.id}]`).on("click", function() {
       // I did something like this
       (`#${user.id}`).remove(); // But this didn't work
    })
  }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in the logic used in your click event callback:

- The variable `id` is not accessible in the callback. A quick fix will be to fix the reference so that you are using `user.id` in the selector instead. Also, you can simply remove it by ID without needing to search for it inside its parent element, since it is unique.
- Your selector `[data-id]=${user.id}` is syntacically incorrect. I suppose you meant `[data-id=${user.id}]`
- You should be using `.remove()` to remove a node

A quick fix will look like this:

```
$(`button[data-id=${user.id}].remove`).on("click", function() {
   $(`#${user.id}`).remove();
});
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
function generateUserCard(id) {
  return `
    <div class="user-card" id="${id}">
      User ID: ${id}
      <button data-id="${id}" class="add" >Add</button>
      <button data-id="${id}" class="remove" >Remove</button>
    </div>
  `;
}

function generateUsers(users) {
  const userGrid = $("#user-grid");
  for (let user of users) {
    const userCard = generateUserCard(user.id);
    userGrid.append(userCard);

    $(`button[data-id=${user.id}].remove`).on("click", function() {
      $(`#${user.id}`).remove();
    })
  }
}

// For demo only
let i = 0;
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  const userArray = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    i++;
    userArray.push({ id: i });
  }
  generateUsers(userArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Generate users</button>
<div id="user-grid"></div>
```

However, an improvement to your code will be to avoid adding new click event listeners to all your newly appended elements. You can simply listen to the click event bubbling up to a parent that is already present at runtime (e.g. `#user-grid`), and you can bind it outside of your `generateUsers` function:

```
$('#user-grid').on('click', 'button.add, button.remove', function() {
  const id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $(`#${id}`).remove();
});
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
function generateUserCard(id) {
  return `
    <div class="user-card" id="${id}">
      User ID: ${id}
      <button data-id="${id}" class="add" >Add</button>
      <button data-id="${id}" class="remove" >Remove</button>
    </div>
  `;
}

function generateUsers(users) {
  const userGrid = $("#user-grid");
  for (let user of users) {
    const userCard = generateUserCard(user.id);
    userGrid.append(userCard);
  }
}

// Listen to event bubbling instead!
$('#user-grid').on('click', 'button.remove', function() {
  const id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $(`#${id}`).remove();
});

// For demo only
let i = 0;
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  const userArray = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    i++;
    userArray.push({
      id: i
    });
  }
  generateUsers(userArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Generate users</button>
<div id="user-grid"></div>
```

Comment: I have fixed first two typos. So you can maybe remove first two points for others user's convinient. Also, i think this answer will work well. I will let ypu know in a moment. THANK YOU SO MUCH